# Remove part of a string in PHP

Tags: php

How can I keep a part from a string:

```
$str = '../assets/uploads/8b3da36c4bce050/_hd/791df3a1355efd3.jpg';
```

I want to keep all after `/_hd/`.

I try with this but it keeps the `hd/`:

```
echo substr($str, strpos($str, '_hd/') + 1);
// hd/791df3a1355efd3.jpg
```

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: Try +4 instead of +1

Comment: `echo array_pop(explode('/',$str));`

Comment: Another approach is exploiding the sring by the `/_hd/` and getting last element of the created array. Or even exploding by slash only to get URL's parts into an array

Comment: This is almost the textbook definition of an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What you're trying to do is get the filename from a full path; concentrate on that and you'll find it a lot easier than parsing the string manually.

Answer (score 1):

you could simply use [`pathinfo`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo) method which will parse your `path` and return an `array` like this

```php
array(4) {
  ["dirname"]=>
  string(37) "../assets/uploads/8b3da36c4bce050/_hd"
  ["basename"]=>
  string(19) "791df3a1355efd3.jpg"
  ["extension"]=>
  string(3) "jpg"
  ["filename"]=>
  string(15) "791df3a1355efd3"
}
```

for you what you are looking for will be called `basename`

```php
$path = '../assets/uploads/8b3da36c4bce050/_hd/791df3a1355efd3.jpg';

echo pathinfo($path)['basename']; // 791df3a1355efd3.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering the example string witch appears to be a path and also assuming it is a single line, I propose a couple of examples with the first preferred.

```
<?php
$str = '../assets/uploads/8b3da36c4bce050/_hd/791df3a1355efd3.jpg';

echo basename($str);
```

This will output `791df3a1355efd3.jpg`

```
<?php
$str = '../assets/uploads/8b3da36c4bce050/_hd/791df3a1355efd3.jpg';

echo preg_replace('#^.+\/#', '', $str);
```

This will output `791df3a1355efd3.jpg`

With the second example if you also wanted to make sure /_hd/ is in the string

```
<?php
$str = '../assets/uploads/8b3da36c4bce050/_hd/791df3a1355efd3.jpg';
echo preg_replace('#^.+\/_hd\/#', '', $str);
```

and to get an array of values checking if /_hd/ is in the string (you can use `basename()` instead of `preg_replace()`)

```
<?php
$str = '../assets/uploads/8b3da36c4bce050/_hd/791df3a1355efd3.jpg';
$files = array();

if (preg_match('#\/_hd\/#',  $str)) {
    $files[] = preg_replace('#^.+\/_hd\/#', '', $str);
}

var_dump($files);
```

echo is for testing but you can assign the result to a variable instead in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the explode function

```
<?php 

$str = '../assets/uploads/8b3da36c4bce050/_hd/791df3a1355efd3.jpg';

$explode = explode('/',$str);

echo $result = $explode['5'];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this, for example

```php
$name = substr($str, strrpos($str, '/', -1) + 1);
```

or

```php
$items = explode($str, '/');
$name = $items[count($items) - 1];
```